# Recording on the Mac machine Android scripts for appium and run them on the Windows machine using Appium

Tags: android, windows, macos, appium, inspector

Since Appium's inspector is not conducive recording scripts on Windows, I am using AppiumForWindows coupled with uiautomatorviewer from SDK time to identify app objects and actions to send. I know that we can easily use recording option on Mac in order to record the flow and run it on Mac using appium.

However, I wanted to know if i can switch to Mac just for recording my android app script on the Mac machine and go then to my favourite windows machine for running them using appium? I cannot test now because I have not Mac yet. I told myself that it is possible because of the use of java language (multi-platform) and the fact that Appium provides a standard API both Android and iOS for automation but at the same time, I have doubts because of that answer, I have found on line  at https://discuss.appium.io/t/can-we-record-the-script-on-mac-machine-using-appium-tool-and-re-run-the-recorded-script-on-android-or-window-phone-using-appium/5938
I want to decide myself finally. Please i want to know what you think about.

Comment: If I am not getting you wrong, is your concern recording the scripts using MAC and running them on Windows?

Comment: yes as you said, that is recording using MAC and running them on Windows!

Comment: Should work fine in that case. You are just taking a piece of code which is not dependent on the platform you chose to code it on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No, Appium api's are cross platform compatible, however the id's and paths which you use to locate the object under test in both platforms are different, which could cause the script to not work.

I have not used the recorder as such, however if both apps are exactly similar, one could create same test case, with maximum reusable in locating an object by accesibility tag (provided both are kept the same).

Comment: As you have said the id's and paths which you use to locate the object under test in both platforms are different, Is that due to the wrapper embedded in the Appium framework which translates Selenium Webdriver API into UIAutomator (for Android) and UIAutomation (for iOS)?

Comment: Nothing to do with Appium per se.. it is more to do with the differences in each platform, many commercial tools such as SeeTest, TouchMobile offers interesting work around over this problem

Comment: your answer helps understand better thank you Azlam!

Comment: While waiting to receive the MAC machine I have installed appium on Linux successfully but no GUI like the client appium.exe on Windows . Do you know if there exist a GUI wrapper appium on Linux? Thanks!